# Is it possible to use `retry` keyword inline with `if`?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, inline

I have to surround everything with `begin`-`rescue`-`end` block. I've written code that looks like:

```
begin
  bet = Dialogs.enter_your_bet
  approx.calculate_average_profit(bet)
  approx.print_profits_table
  retry if Dialogs.play_again?
rescue;retry
end
```

The line `retry if Dialogs.play_again?` caused the following error:

```
./main:14: Invalid retry
./main: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

Is it possible to make this kind of inline `retry` to work with `if` clause without regular `if`-`end` multiline approach?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I use it all the time.

Comment: `rescue` is used to handle exceptions. Don't use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: Do you want to `retry` in case of an exception. Or do you want to re-run the block if the condition is met? You might want to use a `while` block in the second case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you all for answers! I understood what was a problem, but your workarounds wasn't what I need. Actually, rescue part was for restarting input prompt in case of illegal input from a user, while my 'retry' inside begin was to restart block from another user input (y/n question).

So after some investigation, this code would work flawlessly:

```
begin
  loop do
    bet = Dialogs.enter_your_bet(gapes[0],gapes[1])
    approx.calculate_average_profit(bet)
    approx.print_profits_table
  break if !Dialogs.play_again?
  end
rescue;retry
end
```

And again, thanks for been so awesomely active community. Take care!

Comment: `if !Dialogs.play_again?` is equivalent to `unless Dialogs.play_again?`

Comment: @Stefan yes, surly. Yet I have a terrible headache using 'unless' keyword, so I got rid of it :)

Comment: Note that you are `retry`-ing the whole `loop` in case of an exception. I would wrap the `loop`'s body in a `begin-rescue-end` block and remove the `retry`.

Comment: @Stefan in my particular case it's ok, as I store all the necessary info in approx object instance that was created before. But again - thanks for an observation.

Answer (score 5):

`retry` works in `rescue` blocks (or in iterators). And it works with `if`. Try this:

```
begin
  bet = Dialogs.enter_your_bet
  approx.calculate_average_profit(bet)
  approx.print_profits_table
rescue
  retry if Dialogs.play_again?
end
```

Comment: The `rescue` block is only called if an exception is raised.

Comment: @Stefan yes, you're right. And that's why this implementation is not what I want (my mistake, maybe I should explain what I need more clearly).  I selfanswered this question with a possible workaround to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

[redo](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-redo+Statement) is used for control flow.

Quoting the docs: "In Ruby 1.8 you could also use retry where you used redo. This is no longer true, now you will receive a SyntaxError when you use retry outside of a rescue block. See Exceptions for proper usage of retry."

Comment: There's no way to exit the loop.